# PHP - fwrite() does not write to socket

Tags: php, sockets, fgets, fwrite, fsockopen

I'm working on an object-oriented application in PHP that connects to a remote server to read and send data. To do this, I am using `fsockopen()`, `fgets()` to read, `fwrite()` to write and `fclose()`.
I simplified it to just the neccessary code:

```
<?php
namespace myApplication;

class client {
    protected $socket;
    public $connected = false;
    
    public function connect(string $host, int $port) : bool {
        if (($this->socket = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 15)) == false) {
            return false; //or error handling
        }
        $this->connected = true;
        return true;
    }
    
    public function disconnect() {
        if ($this->connected) {
            @fclose($this->socket);
            $this->connected = false;
        }
    }
    
    
    public function read() : ?string {
        if ($this->connected === false) {
            /*
            throw error
            */
        }
        
        if (($data = fgets($this->socket)) !== false) {
            return $data;
        }
        else {
            /*
            error handling
            */
        }
    }
    
    public function write($write_data) : bool {
        if ($this->connected === false) {
            /*
            throw error
            */
        }
        
        $write_data .= "\r\n"; //carriage return, newline
        if (fwrite($this->socket, $write_data, strlen($write_data)) != false) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            /*
            error handling
            */
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

## The Problem

First it seems like everything works as expected. The client connects to the server, **it successfully retrieves the first greeting line sent by the server** and as `fwrite()` is called it returns that it successfully wrote all bytes. (PHP Documentation says the function's return value is the number of written bytes.) So all this seems to work just fine.

**But** the server nevers gets data from the client. I tested the client with a little bare-bone PHP socket server that I wrote for debugging purposes, but it also does not retrieve any data from the client.

I don't know why this is the case. The connection is being established successfully and as mentioned the client can *retrieve* data from the server. But for any reason, `fwrite()` does not successfully sent the data.

There are no error or warning messages. Log level `E_ALL`.

## Versions and Information:

- **OS:** Debian 10 Buster, all software packages on newest version.
- **`php --version` output:** PHP 7.3.19-1~deb10u1

For further information please ask here, I will be active and answering questions.

Comment: Shouldn't `$write_data .= '\r\n';` be `$write_data .= "\r\n";`? ie with double quotes...

Comment: Yeah, you're right! I made the mistake as I wrote the snippet for this question, my bad.
I have edited the question and fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that in this case `fwrite` only writes to a Buffer instead of directly sending the data.
To force the sending [`fflush`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fflush.php) can be used.

Comment: Thanks, this worked so far! But why is it neccessary to use `fflush` in this case?
Also, the behaviour of the application is still weird. The data is only sent after approximately 60 seconds from establishing the connection and altough I am calling the `::disconnect()` function of the class after sending and reading one line (in this case the server sends only one line after the client sent his data) the script only finishes after another ~40-60 seconds since the data was sent. Are there reasons why this is that way? The servers also reports two incoming lines of data.

Comment: I wasn't able to find further information on the buffering in the PHP documentation. 
The delays seam odd to me and I can't even come up with a reasonable guess right now.